# Using Update on Delta table is changing the state of an intermediate DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am facing a situation here.
So below are the steps I am using to transform my DataFrame

```
val filteringRecordsToExpire = collectAllActiveRecords.join(collectingSrcSysIdsToExpire, Seq("trans_id"), "leftsemi") 

filteringRecordsToExpire contains few of the IDS which I need to make Invalid

val expiredList = filteringRecordsToExpire.select("trans_id").distinct().collect()

expiredList.foreach(v => expireRecords(v(0).toString)) --> Here I am Updating each record
```

Now I want to use those Same IDs that I expired and further want to re-Enter them in the same Table with some new Values.

But I am getting an Empty DataFrame After I perform the Expire ( Which is basically updating the existing table for those same IDs )
`collectingSrcSysIdsToExpire` - So this DataFrame holds all those IDs which further I want to modify and INSERT into the Table.
But in this process The Whole Dataframe is going empty.
I have tried persisting this dataframe and Also registered to a Temp Table and tried using it. But nothing is working.

Any Help or suggestion would be a big help. Thanks in advance.

-----------------------------solution----------------------------------

So here is how I solved this issue.
As Suggested I used MERGE INTO which was a lot faster and as I am using unique transaction ids so I dint have any duplicate issues. Previously I was Updating the table for those transaction IDS then tried to use those same unique IDs with modified values and INSERT INTO the same table.

As a solution I first picked distinct transaction ids from my source and INSERT INTO the table with my updated values , then stored those same list of transaction ids and updated existing older record entries from the table.

```
val filteringRecordsToExpire = delta.join(collectingSrcSysIdsToExpire, Seq("trans_id"), "leftsemi")
.distinct()

collectingSrcSysIdsToExpire.select(TargetTable.schema.map(f => col(f.name)): _*).write.insertInto(Table)

val sqlUpdateQry =
      s""" MERGE INTO TargetTable as tgtTable
           USING expireSrsIds as source
           ON tgtTable.trans_id = source.trans_id
           AND few more conditions 
           WHEN MATCHED
           THEN UPDATE SET
           expiring older entries
```

So somehow INSERT then UPDATE works sequentially.
But UPDATE then INSERT does not work.

Comment: The Same problem worked when I did Insert into table first then used MERGE to update the existing records. Very weird.. I am updating the question

Answer (score 2):

The `foreach` is by definition doesn't return any data - you can see from [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#foreach(f:T=%3EUnit):Unit) that the return type is `Unit`.  I also don't recommend to update individual records - it will be too slow as it will rewrite the data for each record separately.  Instead, use the `MERGE` operation, with something like this (it's not Scala, just algorithm):

```scala
sourceTable
  .as("source")
  .merge(
    dfUpdates.as("updates"),
    "source.id = updates.id")
  .whenMatched
  .updateExpr(
    Map(
      "status" -> "'expired"
    ))
```

See [MERGE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-update#--upsert-into-a-table-using-merge) for full details. Also instead of updating records, you can delete them.

Comment: What doesn’t solve? As I mentioned, foreach by definition doesn’t return result. If you still want to use your approach, use map function instead

Comment: Hello Alex, Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried now using MERGE and ofcourse the update happened very fast. Thank you. But still that does not solve my problem.
So now val filteringRecordsToExpire = collectAllActiveRecords.join(collectingSrcSysIdsToExpire, Seq("trans_id"), "leftsemi") --> These unique keys coming from filteringRecordsToExpire  I used MERGE to update,now I want to use same unique keys inserted with some updated values. Intermediate Dataframe is empty.

Comment: I saw few references where it is mentioned that Delta Table takes a snapshot of the table. And in the job if it gets updated it looses the instances. So probably its not able to refer back to my intermediate records.

Comment: Please update your post with what you want to do, not how are you doing it